# Create .NET 2.0 AppDomain in .NET 4.0 process

Tags: c#, .net, clr, appdomain

I need to dynamically create a .NET 2.0 compatible assembly from within my .NET 4.0 process. Currently it is achieved with this:

```
AssemblyBuilder ab = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(...)
ModuleBuilder  mb = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(...);
```

But unfortuntely all dll's produced are .NET 4.0 (inherited from my 4.0 process) which doesn't work with my other .NET 2.0 processes.

Any idea how 2 different CLR versioned AppDomains can co-exist in the same process?

Comment: I am hoping for something like: AppDomain.Create("V2.0", ..., ...)

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at this question: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/clr/thread/1bfd7f40-fd57-4c9f-803f-aa4b19214af9.

Paul Zhou explains, that it is possible to host multiple CLRs in the same Windows process and provides the following links with more detailed information:

- [CLR Hosting APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163567.aspx)
- [Creating a host application for the .NET Common Language Runtime](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/simpleclrhost.aspx)
- [Host CLR](http://1code.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Invoke%20.NET%20Assembly%20from%20Native%20C%2b%2b)

However, the links look like this is not exactly a trivial task...